# How do I create pagination with live search using php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have been adding pagination to a live search. currently the call go through jquery that call search.php and display the data in a id in the homepage. The pagination is showing up but it only stays on one page. I cannot get it to display data on page 2 or 3 etc. Below if I manually change the variable $start by putting a number it would change to the page.  Do you know how to correct it?

between the sql to get the count and the while loop I have the following:

```
$per_page = 1;
$start =  isset($_POST['start']) ? $_POST['start']: '';
$max_pages = ceil($count[0]/$per_page);
if (!$start)
$start = 0;
```

After closing the while loop I have the pagination data:

```
 echo "<center>";
    $prev = $start - $per_page;
    $next = $start + $per_page;

    if (!($start <= 0))
    echo "<a href='search.php?search=$key&submit=search&start=$prev'>&nbspPrev&nbsp</a>";

    $i=1;
    for ($x=0; $x<$count; $x=$x +$per_page) {
    if ($start != $x)
    echo "<a href='search.php?search=$key&submit=search&start=$x'>&nbsp$i&nbsp</a>";
    else
    echo "<a href='search.php?search=$key&submit=search&start=$x'><b>&nbsp$i&nbsp</b></a>";

    $i++;
}
if (!($start >= $count - $per_page ))
echo "<a href='search.php?search=$key&submit=search&start=$next'>&nbspNext&nbsp</a>"; 
    echo "</center>";
```

Comment: Uh, clicking a link would be a $_GET, not $_POST

Comment: not working when I change it to $_GET. That is why I change it to $_POST. At the beginning the sql take in a string and I am using $_POST.

Comment: You should do some echos to a file or console or something against $_GET and $_POST to make sure you are getting the value you expect.

Comment: It echo in the link of the pagination section. I am even trying to pass the start value in the jquery link. It just keeping me on one page. It is not going to the next page. The link is changing but the data isn't changing.

Comment: @Taplar. in my browser I have: http://www.foo.com/who.php?pn=3&text=walk. While I did a echo server: "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];   I got this: http://www.foo.com?text=walk. I believe that I was passing the browser info so I try to get the page number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a live search index page that call a script(jquery) that call a php. My pagination code was not going to the next page. What I did was put a hidden input to get the value from $_POST['start']; on the index page. I using already using a script (JQUERY) to put the value in the text area from the url for the text input and retrieve it so I did the same for the page increment. I get the value from the url put it into the hidden input and retrieve it with my script (JQUERY). You see me using $_GET and $_POST. I had a difficult time figuring it out. Hope this help.